# Summing Booleans in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a non-indexed Pandas dataframe where each row consists of numeric and boolean values with some NaNs. An example row in my dataframe might look like this (with variables above):

```
X_1  X_2  X_3 X_4   X_5  X_6 X_7  X_8  X_9   X_10  X_11  X_12
24.4 True 5.1 False 22.4 55  33.4 True 18.04 False NaN   NaN
```

I would like to add a new variable to my dataframe, call it `X_13`, which is the number of True values in each row. So in the above case, I would like to obtain:

```
X_1  X_2  X_3 X_4   X_5  X_6 X_7  X_8  X_9   X_10  X_11  X_12 X_13
24.4 True 5.1 False 22.4 55  33.4 True 18.04 False NaN   NaN  2
```

I have tried `df[X_13] = df[X_2] + df[X_4] + df[X_8] + df[X_10]` and that gives me what I want unless the row contains a `NaN` in a location where a Boolean is expected. For those rows, `X_13` has the value `NaN`.

Sorry -- this feels like it should be absurdly simple. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

Select boolean columns and then sum:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['bool']).sum(axis=1)
```

If you have NaNs, first fill with False's:

```
df.fillna(False).select_dtypes(include=['bool']).sum(axis=1)
```

---

Consider this DataFrame:

```
df
Out: 
       a      b  c     d
0   True  False  1  True
1  False   True  2   NaN
```

`df == True` returns True for (0, c) as well:

```
df == True
Out: 
       a      b      c      d
0   True  False   True   True
1  False   True  False  False
```

So if you take the sum, you will get 3 instead of 2. Another important point is that boolean arrays [cannot contain NaNs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions). So if you check the dtypes, you will see:

```
df.dtypes
Out: 
a      bool
b      bool
c     int64
d    object
dtype: object
```

By filling with `False`s you can have a boolean array:

```
df.fillna(False).dtypes
Out: 
a     bool
b     bool
c    int64
d     bool
dtype: object
```

Now you can safely sum by selecting the boolean columns.

```
df.fillna(False).select_dtypes(include=['bool']).sum(axis=1)
Out: 
0    2
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Very nice - can you add some sample where explain it? Maybe some value 1 and combination boolean True and NaN is necessary in one column. +1